# How should one read the DharmaShastras?

Tags: scripture, dharma-shastras

I am looking to eventually read the Dharma Shastras... but I don't know how to approach them, so I would like some information about how to read the Dharma Shastras. (Like, when to read them, which one to start with, etc.)

Comment: PV Kane ( Indian Indologist) ,has written a book  called **History of Dharmaśāstra** , analysing manuscripts  on dharmashastras, This book will come in handy , for inquisitive readers .(also as dharmashastras span across yugas ,this book would be useful to get the right interpretation in context )

Comment: @Arthrey could you give me a pdf of the the book?